# In a DFA, does trapped state have a transition on every symbol of the alphabet?

Tags: state, dfa

if DFA machine trapped-state is q# and my alphabet is {a,b},does q# need a and b self-edges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes since it has to show that there is no way to get to another state.

Answer (score 0):

If your DFA needs to be complete, yes. In a complete DFA, all states have all transitions explicitly defined.